# IOS UIWebView register the selector by class_addMethod and register the protocol by objc_registerProtocol , but jscontext can't callback it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, javascriptcore

i use the JSExport protocol to create the new protocol and use  class_addMethod to create the new selector then the JSContext can call it. but it dose not work .

the code is

```
- (BOOL)setupRunJsContextSelector
{
      BOOL success = YES;
      for (NSString* key in [_runJsCallbackDic allKeys]) {
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(key);
        if (![self respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            success = class_addMethod([self class], selector, (IMP)doRunJsContextCompletion, "v@:");
        }
    }

    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"setupRunJsContext failed");
    }
    return success;
 }
```

and

```
 - (void)setupRunJsContextProtocol
  {
    if (!_runJsContextProtocol) {
        _runJsContextProtocol =  objc_allocateProtocol ("RunJsContextProtocol");
        if (!_runJsContextProtocol) {
            return ;
        }
        protocol_addProtocol(_runJsContextProtocol, @protocol(JSExport));
        objc_registerProtocol(_runJsContextProtocol);
    }

    if (!class_conformsToProtocol([self class], _runJsContextProtocol)) {
        class_addProtocol([self class], _runJsContextProtocol);
    }

    if (_runJsContextProtocol) {
        for (NSString* key in [_runJsCallbackDic allKeys]) {
            protocol_addMethodDescription(_runJsContextProtocol,         NSSelectorFromString(key), "v@:", YES, YES);
          }
      }
  }
```

the above functions is used to register protocol and selector,  then  i call the uiwebview method that to register jscontex, follow code

```
JSContext *jsContext = [_webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
jsContext[path] = _runJsContext;
jsContext.exceptionHandler = ^(JSContext *context, JSValue *exceptionValue) {
    context.exception = exceptionValue;
    NSLog(@"exception：%@", exceptionValue);
};
```

what's wrong happened?  how can i fix it? thanks for your answer.